# Cropping images with ImageMagic produces wrong size images - why?

Tags: imagemagick, image-manipulation

There is a bunch of images that represent the pages, scanned from a book and already cropped with ImageMagic. They are all uniform, 629x625 pixels. I need to process them further to prepare for creation of a PDF: split them into odd and even pages. They are named `canvas-00.png` through `canvas-53.png`

When I use the following command to get the odd pages first, I get completely butchered images 275x563 pixels extracted from a wrong horizontal offset:

```
convert canvas-??.png -crop 314x625+0+0 ~/Pictures/odd/canvas.png
```

What am I doing wrong?

PS: Originally the images were larger, contained extra margins with scanner's lid visible, and I successfully cropped them to 629x625 using a very similar command, but of course with non-zero offset of `+140+71`. So it baffles me that a visibly more trivial command with zero offset does not work at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect you have page offsets *"remembered"* in your PNG files and you need to clear them.

As an example, let's create an image 500x300 pixels:

```
convert xc:red xc:lime +append \
   \( xc:blue xc:magenta +append \) -append -resize 500x300\! start.png
```

[image]

Now let's crop out a piece towards the bottom right corner, which I intentionally made magenta so you can see which piece I got:

```
convert start.png -crop 200x100+250+150 z.png
```

[image]

But if we now look at it with `identify` you can see it *"remembers"* where it was in the original picture:

```
identify z.png
```

**Output**

```
z.png PNG 200x100 500x300+250+150 16-bit sRGB 51.1KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

This will then potentially affect (i.e. mess up) anything you do in future with the image. The solution is to use `+repage` to reset all the page geometry and layout so it forgets. You can either do this when cropping, or when using the cropped image later - depending whether you want to retain the crop information or not. (Sometimes you do want it when you are doing jigsaw puzzle processing and maybe want to reassemble the pieces later).

```
convert start.png -crop 200x100+250+150 +repage z.png
identify z.png
z.png PNG 200x100 200x100+0+0 16-bit sRGB 51.1KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

In your case, if you already cropped and saved without repaging, you can load your images and repage prior to actual use:

```
convert canvas-??.png +repage -crop 817x1040+0+0 ~/Pictures/odd/canvas.png
```

Comment: So now, that the intermediate images have remembered their crop, how do I clear them? I no longer have the originals.

Comment: Never mind, the command `for i in *.png; do convert "$i" +repage "~/Pictures/cleared/$i"; done` did the trick.

Comment: Thanks!!!! This is the ONLY answer I found talking about how to convert png to forget its original position. Now, I am wondering if any idea how to make selected layer from psd file to forget its original position.